# How to run console command of Yii2 using cron job in Godaddy web hosting server

Tags: php, linux, yii, cron, yii2

From localhost am using this command to run and its working succesfully

> c:/wamp/www/yii2_advanced>yii test/pending

While am using below command in cron job of godaddy server. its not working

> php public_html/yii2_advanced/ yii test/pending >/dev/null 2>&1

So how can I run console command of Yii2 using cron job in Godaddy web hosting server?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: try to format a bit better what works, what does not, what problems do you face, etc.

Comment: this working in localhost when i use this command   **C:\wamp\www\yii2_advanced>yii test/pending** . when i use this to run cron job in godaddy server using this command **php public_html/yii2_advanced/ yii test/pending >/dev/null 2>&1** , didn't get error, but its not working

Comment: Please [edit] your question with this information, do not complement it with comments.

Comment: look above i have updated it

Comment: I'm not familiar with go daddy but it already looks like there shouldn't be the space between the path and `yii` Also from reading online people seem to use `web/cgi-bin/php5` instead of `php` so all in all maybe try: `web/cgi-bin/php5 $HOME/public_html/yii2_advanced/yii test/pending >/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: still the command doesn't working for me

Answer (score 1):

***I know this is an old post but I have also waste my whole day to figure out this problem.that is why I am posting my answer.Hope this will help some one.***

[image]

1> Enter an email id in above section. It will help you to test.

2> Do not choose time less then 5 minutes.Sometimes it is not working on godaddy.

**Note: email could take up to 20 minutes to trigger, so be patient.**

3>Enter This command after selecting time 5 minutes to test.

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/projectName/yii json/start
```

4>Check your email in order to test your job .If job is not working then here will be an error message.

5> When your cron job is up and running then you do not need any email . To remove email sending add this command

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/projectName/yii json/start >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Your answer helped me find the solution. But, for anyone who is using Hostgator, this page helps finding out the right php path: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/cpanel/what-do-i-put-for-the-cron-job-command

Answer (score 1):

You can use below function in crontab

```
    * * * * * php  /var/www/html/your-project-path/yii test/index
```

Here **yii** points to your root yii file of your Yii project **test** is my console controller and **/index** is my method.

Hope this helps .

Answer (score 0):

Non of these answers work for me. Im using yii2 Hope my solution help someone!

First of all Create your Cron as a new file:  MyCronNameController.php

We will suppose our cron file name is HelloController.php so it codes will look like:

```
    <?php

namespace app\commands;

use yii\console\Controller;

class HelloController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex($message = 'hello world')
    {
        echo $message . "\n";
    }
}
```

One this file is on your hosting, just go to the Cron Job manager into GoDaddy and set the command like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/<user>/public_html/<project-folder>/yii hello
```

Take a look that on the command i just run the command without the "Controller" word.

One more observation is that i try this with a cron name like "HelloWordController" and run it with "helloword", and it didnt work, with only one word name it will work ok.

Answer (score 0):

cronjobs in yii2 ubuntu

#create cronjob every minutes

- - - - - php /var/www/html/yiitest2.0.39/yii test/makefile

https://youtu.be/5KUMNPKgvnU

Answer (score -1):

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /public_html/<YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER_NAME> yii <CONTROLLER_NAME>/<ACTION_NAME>
```

Comment: Could you expand on this please?